# To have site.pages or site.projects of template data in octopress?

Tags: octopress

In official jekyll doc: [Template Data](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Template-Data),  we have *site.posts* for a reverse chronological list of all Posts. Can we have *site.pages* for a list of all Pages? Or, if we create some customized layout, like *project*, how to have *site.projects* for all Projects?